# Are the social-distancing measures implemented against SARS-CoV-2 also suppressing the spread of other viruses?

Tags: virology, theoretical-biology, coronavirus, epidemiology

With social-distancing measures being implemented in many countries I would expect other viruses, like the ones that cause seasonal flus, to have also a hard time propagating in these circumstances. Are there any estimates or research (epidemiological models) I can check, about the possibility we are winning by accident a war against many other less alarming viruses?

Comment: [relevant XKCD](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/common_cold.png)

Comment: @Dirigible [full page](https://xkcd.com/2306/) (so you can read the hover text as well)

Comment: Of course there's an xkcd. How couldn't there be?

Comment: [Anoter relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2287/)

Comment: I think "killing" is the wrong therm here. Social-distancing is reducing the spread of viruses.

Comment: Not enough reputation for an answer, but this is the respiratory infection rate in Germany: https://grippeweb.rki.de/Diagrams/2019_2020/2020-22-01.png It’s at ~2% compared to the usual ~5% for this time of the year. I think this even includes COVID19.

Comment: Not enough rep to answer. Norovirus in Sweden  https://imgs.aftonbladet-cdn.se/v2/images/65de546d-9803-4977-9e51-ba8d44636c6d?fit=crop&h=720&q=50&w=960&s=2d38e1da546acb07b726e76334a900f34c5cbfab

Comment: It seems that at least for pneumonia in the US the lower numbers could be entirely caused by incomplete data. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47265/has-the-number-of-pneumonia-deaths-in-the-us-dramatically-dropped-in-2020

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, this helps as well with other infectious diseases. A good example is the flu, which season was measurably shorter this year than in other years on record. See the figure from the reference 1 for comparision:

[image]

Reference 2 shows that this is also true for other respiratory diseases (figure 2):

[image]

This shows very well that the isolation measures and the social distancing work very well to control such transmissable diseases.

References:

1. [How coronavirus lockdowns stopped flu in its tracks](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-01538-8)
2. [Monitoring respiratory infections in covid-19 epidemics](https://www.bmj.com/content/369/bmj.m1628.full)

Comment: The flatline of on that second chart is absolutely remarkable compared to previous years.  I wonder if these effects will last a significant period of time or if spread of common viruses will be back to normal next year.

Comment: Of course there are possible reasons for that flatline in addition to limiting the spread.  For instance, people who otherwise might have made a doctor visit for the flu may have decided to skip it this year.

Comment: @jamesqf That graphic is as a percentage of analysed specimens, so those people staying home are not part of the sample at all. Additionally, "there may be other contributing factors, such as people choosing not to go to a place where sick people often congregate" is really killing two birds with one stone in this specific case.

Comment: Looks like the flu season was off to an unfortunately strong start before social-distancing guidelines and lock-downs were put in-place, then presumably the safety procedures helped drive the curve down.  But for reference, is there some simple way to qualitatively describe when lock-down procedures kicked in?

Comment: The second chart makes it seem like there was a single case of covid-19 and then all diseases dropped.  Given it became a global pandemic, I'd expect at least one line to shoot up before the drop.

Comment: @DavidStarkey The chart does not include COVID-19, since it is not an influenza. As you said, once the pandemic was declared everywhere people started to apply precautions (whether imposed by the government or not) and thus all other deaseses started to drop pretty quickly.

Comment: @DavidStarkey, if you look into the reference, that chart *only* applies to Hong Kong. Given their proximity to mainland China, they started taking aggressive precautions before COVID showed up, as I recall.

Answer (score 41):

In addition to Chris' answer above, the effect is even more pronounced in Southern Hemisphere countries where flu season started during the pandemic.  The New Zealand lockdown and health response dramatically lowered the prevalence of reported flu-like symptoms.
[image: Flu in New Zealand, 2020 is much lower than other years]

Reference:
  [Flu Tracking reports - New Zealand – week ending 31-May-2020](https://info.flutracking.net/reports-2/new-zealand-reports/)

Comment: NZ's winter is only just beginning, and their lockdown is over.

Comment: @curiousdannii flu season =/= winter, flu season lasts a lot longer

Comment: I don't have points to write my own answer, but this is a great account of Lab confirmed flu cases in Australia over the past few years and early 2020 (updated 15 June). https://www.immunisationcoalition.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/15Jun-Aust-Flu-Stats-2020.pdf